# UIImageView a subview of UITableViewCell is falling to edges of iPhone Device iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

`UITableViewCell` contains a view which holds a `UITextView` and `UIImageView` as subviews. Created all views programatically, image is created using View.Textview.frame. No `Storyboard` is used.
Issue: On first time load of `UITableView`, Text content in `UITextView` is being trimmed and not rendered properly, and `UIImageView` over `UITextView` is falling to right of iPhone Device.

I solved part of the issue (rendering text in textview), by setting `textContainerInset`,  `lineFragmentPadding` and `textview` font to `[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontWidthTrait]` 
I solved it with the help of below post
http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/how-to-get-rid-of-the-padding-insets-in-an-uitextview/#comment-167

Other part of the issue is My `UIImageView` in `UITableViewCell` is falling to right edge of device screen while first time tableview loading. But When I scroll the tableview and dequeue the `TableViewCell`, `UIImageView` is displaying as expected with correct rects and origins. I tried to change rects of image view in many ways but still it is behaving as explained in above scenario. please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the issue:
set

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero, 
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding  = 0
and textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping
```

I think setting

```
preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontWidthTrait
```

creates extra lines in edge as the size of textContent increases. So not required. Just set default font size.
For the second part of the issue:
Set the frame of imageView as the textView and set clipToBounds property on imageView to YES. By default it is NO.

```
 self.imageView.clipToBounds = YES
```

Hope these two steps solve your issue.

Comment: Yes this is exactly What I need. Thanks.